# Why exactly is --skip-slave-start recommended with MySQL `START SLAVE UNTIL`?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

When issuing `START SLAVE UNTIL` on MySQL , I'm getting the following:

```
Warning: It is recommended to use --skip-slave-start when doing step-by-step replication with START SLAVE UNTIL; otherwise, you will get problems if you get an unexpected slave's mysqld restart.
```

Why exactly is it recommended to use `--skip-slave-start`? What happens if the slave indeed restarts - does it only forget the `UNTIL` part and replicates till the end of binlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it only forget the UNTIL part and replicates till the end of binlog?

That's right.

If a previously configured slave is started without `--skip-slave-start`, then it will use the information stored in `master.info` to automatically reconnect and continue replication like normal - that is without the `UNTIL` clause. Which means proceeding to the end of the binlog and waiting for new binlog events.

Comment: Thanks, I hope there are no other hidden reasons :)